# Getting HandsomeSoup Example to Work

Tags: html, parsing, haskell, types, html-parsing

I've copied the handsomesoup [basic example](https://github.com/egonSchiele/HandsomeSoup/blob/master/examples/GoogleSearch.hs) verbatim, but I'm getting a weird type error. The types are the same, except that some have hxt-9.3.1.3... prepended to some. Does anyone know how to fix that? Thanks!

```
Couldn't match type `hxt-9.3.1.3:Control.Arrow.IOStateListArrow.IOSLA
                       (hxt-9.3.1.3:Text.XML.HXT.Arrow.XmlState.TypeDefs.XIOState ())'
              with `IOSLA (XIOState ())'
```

Comment: It works for me. What Haskell system and version are you using?  For example, cabal installed a different version of hxt for me: hxt-9.3.1.4

Comment: GHC 7.6.3, cabal 1.18. I had hxt-9.3.1.4 and hxt-9.3.1.3 at the same time, which was causing the issue. The solution was to unregister the old version of hxt and handsomesoup, and then reinstall handsomesoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An educated guess would be that `HandsomeSoup` you have installed was built with a different version of `hxt` than the most recent one present in your system, and so when you try to use both libraries at the same time you end up with two colliding versions of `hxt`. Even though cabal tries to prevent such situations, flags such as `--force-reinstalls` can lead to this sort of trouble. In any case, if my guess is correct unregistering `HandsomeSoup` (`ghc-pkg unregister HandsomeSoup`) and then reinstalling it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I'm relatively new to haskell and that was the first error with packages I've encountered.